# Getting Stack Overflow Error on newly created classes

Tags: c#, stack, overflow

I'm refactoring my 8080 Space Invaders emulator. I've moved some methods into a CPU class and others into a _8080 class. I'm using Visual Studio so there's a MainForm class to. When I run the program now I'm getting a Stack Overflow error on the CPU class declaration in the _8080 class. The thing is, when I remove that to test, I get it on the MainForm declaration and then in the CPU class I get it for the same declarations in that class.

This is the whole of the _8080 class

```
namespace SpaceInvaders
{
    class _8080
    {
        private CPU cpu = new CPU(); // ERROR IS THROWN HERE **
        private MainForm MainForm = new MainForm();

        public void StartEmulator()
        {
            cpu.initialiseEmulator(); // Reset 

            LoadProgram("invaders.rom"); // Load ROM

            cpu.emulateCPU();
        }

        private bool LoadProgram(string filename)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nLoading: " + filename + "\n");
            //Initialize();  //reset

            //load file
            byte[] loadedProgramBytes = null;
            try
            {
                loadedProgramBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(Ex.ToString());
            }

            //verify file is not empty
            if (loadedProgramBytes == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error loading program.  The byte array loaded is null.");
                return false;
            }

            int lSize = loadedProgramBytes.Count();

            for (int i = 0; i < lSize; ++i)
            {
                cpu.memory[i] = loadedProgramBytes[i]; // Store file into memory.
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("ROM loaded in successfully.\n");
            return true;
        }

        private void updateScreen(int addr, int val)
        {
            int x = addr >> 5;
            int y = 255 - ((addr & 0x1f) << 3);

            for (int bit = 1; bit <= 128; bit <<= 1)
            {
                //screenBuffer.SetPixel(x, y--, (bit & val) != 0 ? Color.White : Color.Black);
            }

            //Bitmap clone = (Bitmap)screenBuffer.Clone();
            //MainForm.pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = clone;
        }

    }
}
```

The exception thrown is

> System.StackOverflowException   HResult=0x800703E9   Message=Exception
> of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.

Anyone know how to fix this? I'm new to the site so not sure how things work, posting long class text etc. I don't want to overload people with code but at the same time I understand that without enough information it's hard to help. If it helps I've added three Pastebin's of each of the classes in the program below.

https://pastebin.com/gYhhQd5D << MainForm Class

https://pastebin.com/MhdGwanm << _8080 Class

https://pastebin.com/T9t6dNjL << CPU Class

Thanks.

Comment: And the complete error text is? (possibly your CPU constructor is calling itself, but without more details can't answer for sure)

Comment: Where's the code for `CPU`?

Comment: The code in CPU is pretty long so I didn't want to post it here. Is there some way I can add the full class without making the page scroll for ages?

Comment: @J.Salas added the exception text to the post. It's pretty much just a stack overflow.

Comment: with complete I mean the StackTrace ;) as I said if the error is thrown when you call new CPU() the problem seems to be  that the constructor of the CPU class is calling itself, stackOverflow in c# usually is caused by a infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove :

```
    private _8080 _8080 = new _8080();
    private MainForm MainForm = new MainForm();
```

from the CPU class (for the paste bin code you aren't using them there)

In 8080 your code uses the cpu and the mainform

In Mainform your code uses (comented) the 8080

So, in Mainform create the global cpu and pass it to the other constructors

```
    private CPU cpu = new CPU(); //Remember you removed from cpu class the 2 lines with the new ....
    private _8080 _8080 = new _8080(this, cpu);
    
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

   [...]
```

And the 8080 class remove the inizialitations and add a constructor:

```
    private CPU cpu;
    private MainForm MainForm;

    public 8080( MainForm _MainForm, CPU _cpu)
    {
        cpu = _cpu;
        MainForm = _MainForm;
    }
```

// Note that for minimizing the code changes I'm using incorrectly the naming conventions., don't do it at home guys

Answer (score 0):

The CPU Constructor is calling the MainForm constructor, which is calling the CPU constructor which is...

It's most likely due to the infinite loop of constructor calls.

For example

```
class _8080 {
    private CPU cpu;
    private MainForm MainForm;

    public _8080 (CPU cpu, MainForm, mainForm) {
        this.cpu = cpu;
        this.MainForm = mainform;
    }
}
```

apply this to the CPU and MainForm class as well

Comment: How would I fix that?

Comment: you could initialise each class, the 8080, cpu and mainform separately, then pass them as parameters so that you are using the same referenced object instead of multiple new instances

Comment: ive added a small example